# Threaded for loop in c++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, for-loop

I am trying to figure out the best way to essentially thread a for loop. For example, if I have the following loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  doSomethingThreadSafe(i);
```

This will be on a Windows platform. I have played around with creating a thread for each processor, and then attempting to divide n up as evenly as possible for each processor. Then I pass the necessary data to each thread, and then use a WaitForMultipleThreads. Is there a better way to do this? I don't want to use any other library like boost.

Ideally, I would like some generic (perhaps templated) way to go about this. i.e.

```
threaded_for(0, n, doSomethingThreadSafe);
```

If the best/most efficient way would to be use a library, how much work would be required to add the library, and how exactly would it be used in this example. Still, I prefer a solution with out requiring something else to be added.

Comment: Since you don't want to use an outside library, you won't be able to use [OpenMP](http://www.openmp.org/), which is really what you should be using in this case.

Comment: what are you actually doing in your threads? will there be shared resources that require synchronization?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Everything has been setup so that no synchronization will be required. They will all be doing things independently.

Comment: In that case, what's the issue? Are you trying to divide the work evenly?

Comment: Yes, I just want a generic way to do this. One example would be to have to do something for every column in a 2D array.

Comment: Can parallel_for help you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505035.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way is openMP - visual studio supports it as standard, you just add a couple of magic #pragma to the loop and use all the cores you have !

Best way to learn is how not to do it - [32 OpenMP Traps For C++ Developers](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0054/)

An alternative - but slightly more complex method [Intel TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/)

Answer (score 2):

By far the most efficient way to solve this problem, assuming doSomethingThreadSafe(i) is basically a repeated instruction (single instruction on multiple data) *is* to use OpenMP as chrisaycock says.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    doSomethingThreadSafe(i);
```

It can't get much more simple than that, really.